# Add a Admob banner bottom the page without overlapping content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, admob, android-linearlayout

I want to install a banner at the bottom of the page, but it overlaps the content in main screen.
In the main screen there is a lot of content and there scrolling.

Does anyone know why? 
Thanks.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:androidsam="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jameselsey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout            <!-- CONTENT LAYOUT HERE -->

            android:id="@+id/flContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Put all your application views here, such as buttons, textviews, edittexts and so on -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout" <!-- AdMob LAYOUT -->
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
// Create an ad.
adView = new AdView(context);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view
// will have no size
// until the ad is loaded.
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
layout.getBottom();
layout.addView(adView);

// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the
// hashed device ID to
// get test ads on a physical device.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE").build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it using relative positioning, try for instance setting `above` property to your `home_layout`.-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

**EDIT**

Also, you need to remove the property `layout_alignBottom` from your `ad_layout`.

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
```

**EDIT 2**

Here you have a basic sample to illustrate your scenario.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="200dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/gray" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which results in.-

[image]

A different approach would be changing your root `RelativeLayout` for a vertical `LinearLayout`, speaking of which, if you stick to the `RelativeLayout` you should remove `orientation` attribute.

Comment: I did that but I get an error - IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: It's not work. If a little content - AdMob above content otherwise - not show AdMob

Comment: Mmh still getting the error or still getting the overlapping?

Comment: I see... maybe you should set `home_layout` height to `match_parent`. I added some sample code.

Comment: I'm inserting this code. Space below to advertise there, but AdMob not show there... ( but it is better )

Comment: If there is no internet connection and thus there is no ad to show. Can I make the existing content use the entire screen? I have a scrollview and then the ad banner. Please clarify.

Comment: Yep, set `android:visibility=gone` for the layout containing your ad when you want it to completely disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've solved it this way http://www.ahotbrew.com/how-to-put-admob-banner-on-the-bottom/

Create a relative layout and add the "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"" property to the adview as in the example. Give the list a margin-bottom and it won't overlap.

Comment: If there is no internet connection and thus there is no ad to show can I make the existing content use the entire screen? I have a scrollview and then ad banner. Please clarify.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but there are two places in the example which could help with that. Check line:  params.setMargins(0, 0, 0,   adView.getHeight()+ 15); Try setting this to 0 if there is no internet connection. Otherwise or additionally try modify the layout_height for the view "adView" programmatically and set it to "match_parent".